# Bluemix ignores route information from manifest file

Tags: python, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to to `push` an app to IBM Bluemix Cloud Foundry. The manifest file contains route information like here:

```
applications:
# The Python app starts here
- name: yourname-myapp
  memory: 256M
  command: python myapp.py
  routes:
  - route: myapp.mybluemix.net/app-path
```

I tried it both with a Python and Node.js app. Bluemix seems to ignore the route information and only creates a route `yourname-myapp.mybluemix.net`, not the expected `myapp.mybluemix.net/app-path`. Why?

Comment: Please note that I got it working and it was caused by the CLI version. See my own answer below. And here is my fully working sample https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your installed cf CLI is up-to-date. Pushing an app with route information in the `manifest.yml` requires at least [CLI version 6.21](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases/tag/v6.21.0). See the changelog for version 6.21.

Here is a [sample app with routes including troubleshooting section](https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting), based on my tests.

In general, to find out about deployment or runtime errors of your Bluemix app, you can take a look into the error log. The most recent log entries can be obtained like this:

```
cf logs <application-name> --recent
```

You can also do the following to get a verbose readout of the push in your terminal:

```
CF_TRACE=true cf push yourname-myapp
```

Comment: The question was why the route declaration in the app manifest was ignored and another created.  
The first half of this answer is completely irrelevant to this question: `cf logs` returns application logs and contain nothing about the routes created.  

The **only** answer is to upgrade your cf CLI to 6.21.0 and higher.  

I added my answer (not realizing you were also the author of the question) as the first half of this answer side-tracks people: They may find other warnings/errors in their logs (some frameworks are very verbose) but investigating those will not help with routes.

Comment: You can also do a `CF_TRACE=true cf push yourname-myapp` to get a verbose readout in your terminal.

Comment: I incorporated the feedback into the answer

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a cf CLI version older than 6.21.0.
The cf CLI ignores attributes it does not know so it created and mapped a route based on the app name for you.
You can install the latest cf CLI from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases.

Comment: Did you see my answer that I posted earlier together with the question? I ran into several problems and solved it.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed you were answering your own question. I'll comment on why I added my answer.